# MacBook Pro 13 inch, Mid 2010 external monitor

Tags: macos, display, multiple-monitors, macbook-pro, external-display

I would like to know what is the highest external monitor resolution my [MacBook Pro 13 inch, Mid 2010](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp583) can support?

Also, what connection am I looking at? Mini DisplayPort to what? HDMI?

Comment: "Also, what connection am I looking at? Mini DisplayPort to what? HDMI?" What do you mean?

Comment: What connection is preferable & supported? I understand VGA, DVI and HDMI.

Comment: Right, see my answer. DP is of course preferred, no need for adapters there.

Comment: @DanielBeck, I've updated my question to ask for recommendations. Do you have any?

Comment: We don't provide hardware recommendations. Sorry. [Learn more here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: Note, the answer to all your questions can actually be found on the page linked in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the highest external monitor resolution:

> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on an external display

Output to external monitor is via Mini DisplayPort, so your screen ideally has a DisplayPort input. For other inputs, you can use adapters, but you might not get the highest resolution.

Answer (score 0):

> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native
>   resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on an
>   external display, both at millions of colors